# IORef keeping value if an error occurs

Tags: haskell, exception, ioref

Is there a way to NOT modify IORef value if error happens inside `modifyIORef`?

```
import Data.IORef

main = do
  a <- newIORef (1::Int)

  -- a keeps error now, not Int
  modifyIORef a (const $ error "Error forever")

  val <- readIORef a  -- val is error now
  putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ show val -- throws error
```

Comment: `error` is for errors that should grind everything to a halt, not for routine exceptional conditions.  It's similar to C's `assert` macro.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `IORef` in particular - just force the value with `evaluate` or `deepSeq` (depending on what you actually need) before the call to `modifyIORef`. If the forced expression results in an exception, the call to `modify<..>` is obviously never reached.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this with `modifyIORef'` or `atomicModifyIORef'` wrapped in an exception handler. I wouldn't recommend it in general; `error` calls produce strings for users to read, not detailed info for a handler. And the whole "imprecise exception" mechanism for handling exceptions thrown from "pure" code requires quite a lot of care to use correctly. You're almost always better off making sure never to throw exceptions from pure code. `ExceptT` and `Either` and such can help.

Comment: Understand that it would be best to avoid  `error`. But if some library generates it? :)
`modifyIORef'` is still pure. How can it help me?

Comment: @KaikoKaur, it forces the value before installing it, so you can catch the exception and have the original value there. But why are you calling the library function with a bad argument?

Answer (score -1):

Haskell does not do error handling in the same way that other languages, such as Python and Java, do. When you call the `error` function, the program will halt. Period. The error cannot be caught. There is no way of redirecting it, or restarting the program. The `error` function raises an error, not an exception. If you want to represent the idea of failure in Haskell, you use the `Maybe` and `Either` monads. Below is how you might implement the functionality that you want using the `Either` monad.

```
main = do
  a <- NewIORef (Right 1 :: Either String Int)
  modifyIORef a (const $ Left "some execution error")  
  -- a now holds a "Left" value, representing an error
  val <- readIORef a 
  -- val now holds the "Left" value
  case val of
    Left err -> putStrLn $ "Error: " ++ err -- prints error (if applicable)
    Right val -> putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ show val -- prints value (if applicable)
```

EDIT: 
As dfeuer kindly pointed out in his comment, it *is* possible to intercept errors in GHC. It is, however, considered bad practice except in very specific circumstances, so using the `Maybe` and `Either` types is still preferred.

Comment: An error call *can* be caught in `IO`. It's just not a very good way to handle errors. It's part of GHC's "imprecise exception" system. In standard Report Haskell, what you said is strictly true.